# Declaring set of member functions as friend by using template

Tags: c++, templates, friend

Given the following code:

```
class A;

struct B {
    static void doIt(A* pa);
};

struct C {
    static void doIt(A* pa);
};

class A {
    int i = 9;
    // below works but requires a line per each type
    friend void B::doIt(A* pa);
    friend void C::doIt(A* pa);

    // the below however doesn't work
    // template<typename T>
    // friend void T::doIt(A* pa);
      // (gcc error: member 'void T::doIt(A*)' declared as friend before type 'T' defined)
      // (clang just ignores the above and the error is on accessing A::i in B and C)    
};

void B::doIt(A* pa) {
    cout << pa->i << endl;
}

void C::doIt(A* pa) {
    cout << pa->i *2 << endl;
}

int main() {
    A a;
    B::doIt(&a);
    C::doIt(&a);
}
```

Is it possible to replace the multiple `friend` declarations to allow all `void T::doIt(A* pa)` methods access the private members of `A`?

Trying to instantiate `B` and `C` above `A` doesn't help.

Comment: `template<typename T> friend void T::doIt(A* pa);` isn't a useful declaration. The compiler needs to know the name of the *class*, *function*, *class-template* or *function-template* that befriends `A`. `T` is not a name it knows and it cannot proceed to make every member of `A` accessible to `T`

Comment: Friendship is never a good design choice anyway. It is just a workaround in some "desperate" situations... Take this as an opportunity to revise your design.

Comment: @A.S.H: Not true. Friendship is a great way to enhance encapsulation.

Comment: @ChristianHackl great *"way"*? probably, but that's the point. It's just a *way* to deal with a particular situation where you want to partially expose some hidden data. But it is not a design idiom that I would count on in a design.

Comment: @A.S.H: No, it's a particular situation in which you want to **protect** some hidden data from becoming `public`.

Comment: @ChristianHackl When data is "protected" and the number of such "friends" becomes large (as in the OP's case), it's kind of cheating ourselves. I prefer to make it "clearly" public or find another mechanism, not to use massively the friendship "trick" :)

Comment: @A.S.H: Friendship is not a "trick", and it is not unclear, because it is always declared by the class which grants friendship. Why do you consider it a "trick"? The alternative, as you say, is to make the data `public`, so there is less encapsulation than with `friend`. How is that supposed to be better? A large number of `friend`s may be bad, but a large number of `public` members is worse.

Comment: To be precise, I said make it public OR find some other mechanism or pattern, If some data is to be shared or accessible to a (large) set of classes but not to others, that should raise the question whether this data is *really* the ownership of just one of them. I would find a different design approach, but that's just *my humble opinion*. I highly respect yours of course :)

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what do you asked but... if you templatize the `B`, `C`, etc. structs, you can get something similar.

```
#include <iostream>

class A;

template <std::size_t>
struct X
 { static void doIt(A* pa); };

class A
 {
    int i = 9;

    template <std::size_t I>
    friend void X<I>::doIt (A* pa);
 };

template <>
void X<0U>::doIt(A* pa)
 { std::cout << pa->i << std::endl; }

template <>
void X<1U>::doIt(A* pa)
 { std::cout << pa->i * 2 << std::endl; }

template <>
void X<2U>::doIt(A* pa)
 { std::cout << pa->i * 3 << std::endl; }

using B = X<0U>;
using C = X<1U>;
using D = X<2U>;

int main() {
    A a;
    B::doIt(&a);
    C::doIt(&a);
    D::doIt(&a);
}
```

Comment: Solution works well on g++ (6.3.0) but generates a warning on clang (3.8.0-263969):
    `warning: dependent nested name specifier 'X<I>::' for friend class declaration is not supported; turning off access control for 'A' [-Wunsupported-friend]  friend void X<I>::doIt (A* pa);`
The result in clang is that `A::i` can be acceseed anywhere.
Seems that clang didn't implement this feature yet...

Answer (score 1):

I believe something similar to what you desire can be done using CRTP and private/protected virtual inheritance. The code below is only demonstration and definitely needs some work e.g. to not to involve template method friendship:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class base {
protected:
    int i = 9;
};

template <class F>
class crtp_base: virtual base { // private inheritance!
    template <class T>
    friend void F::doIt(T*);
};

template <class... AllF>
struct crtp_bases: crtp_base<AllF>... { };

struct B {
    template <class T>
    static void doIt(T* pa);
};

struct C {
    template <class T>
    static void doIt(T* pa);
};

class A: public crtp_bases<B, C> {
};

template <class T>
void B::doIt(T* pa) {
    cout << pa->i << endl;
}

template <class T>
void C::doIt(T* pa) {
    cout << pa->i * 2 << endl;
}

int main() {
    A a;
    B::doIt(&a);
    //cout << a.i << endl; // error i is private member of 'base'
}
```

[[live demo]](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/aZe6nJYFhwENlfPd)

Comment: Nice solution. But I don't think I'd like to add the required inheritance into the code.

Answer (score 0):

I see no direct way, but one work-around could be declaring one class with several static methods (instead of several classes with one static method) and then declaring this class as friend, like:

```
...
struct D {
    static void doItB(A* pa);
    static void doItC(A* pa);
};

class A {
...
    friend struct D;
...
};

void D::doItB(A* pa) {
    cout << pa->i << endl;
}

...
    D::doItB(&a);
    D::doItC(&a);
...
```

Comment: The idea is that `doIt` would be implemented in different classes. Still looking for some trick...