# friend method from a template specializated struct: g++ and clang++ different behaviour

Tags: c++, g++, friend, template-specialization, clang++

Trying to propose a solution to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41924069/declaring-set-of-member-functions-as-friend-by-using-template), I bumped (again) my nose against code that compile and work with clang++ (3.5) but give compilation error with g++ (4.9.2)

The following is a simplified minimal (I hope) example

```
#include <iostream>

class foo;

template <std::size_t>
struct bar;

template <>
struct bar<0U>
 { static void baz (foo const & f); };

class foo
 {
    int i = 42;

    template <std::size_t I>
    friend void bar<I>::baz (foo const &);
 };

void bar<0U>::baz (foo const & f)
 { std::cout << f.i << std::endl; }

int main()
 {
    foo f;

    bar<0U>::baz(f);
 }
```

The error from my g++ is

```
test_114-98,11,14,clang.cpp:18:41: error: member ‘void bar<<anonymous> >::baz(const foo&)’ declared as friend before type ‘bar<<anonymous> >’ defined
     friend void bar<I>::baz (foo const &);
                                         ^
test_114-98,11,14,clang.cpp: In static member function ‘static void bar<0ul>::baz(const foo&)’:
test_114-98,11,14,clang.cpp:15:13: error: ‘int foo::i’ is private
     int i = 42;
             ^
test_114-98,11,14,clang.cpp:22:19: error: within this context
  { std::cout << f.i << std::endl; }
                   ^
```

My question, as usual, is: who's right and who's wrong.

Comment: VS2015 indicates the `friends` line and says `An internal error has occurred in the compiler... try simplifying or changing the program near the locations listed above`

Comment: Not so sure about clang. It shouts " warning: dependent nested name specifier 'A<T>::' for friend class declaration is not supported; turning off access control for 'B' " when you try to declare members of class templates that are not yet defined as friends.

Comment: @A.S.H - Internal error occurred in the compiler? D'oh!

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb - I see... starting from clang++ 3.6, according Wandbox. Do you think that g++ is right and that clang++ works only because consider this only a warning?

Comment: Interesting case. What was the original question you were trying to answer? :-)

Comment: @AmirKirsh - an `A`, `B`, `doIt()` question ;-)

Comment: adding to @JohannesSchaub-litb the warning generated by clang (3.8.0-263969) on above code indicates that all members of `foo` become `public` **for everyone** (turning off access control for 'foo'). Now foo members can be publicly accessed everywhere. I don't think this is a useful behavior - I'd prefer if you don't support it give me an error.